# Why FlashPlayer is looking for textLayout_1.1.0.604.swz?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, rsl

I have a flex application, that compiled for flash player version 10.1.

I just realized, when I load the movie in "clean" computer, the movie doesn't work, it try to look for textLayout library. I compile the movie not using RSL.

```
Error #2032: Stream Error. 
URL: http://<hostname>/textLayout_1.1.0.604.swz
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: and it doesn't use streaming?

Comment: I understand that the Text Layout Framework is used in a lot of Flex 4 Spark Classes.  If you compile that library into the SWF, though, it shouldn't be trying to load it. I'm not sure where to point you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are using the Flex Framework RSLs but they aren't configured correctly.  You can disable the Framework RSLs using the `-static-link-runtime-shared-libraries` compiler parameter.  Or you can fix the mis-configured RSL URL.

Answer (score 0):

if you recompiled your application with a different version of SDK than before, then you should update on the server side not only the application's swf but all the others you are using, including textLayout.

in case you don't want to use shared libraries, you should disable it like James Ward said.